# Why do most languages implement wildcard regular expressions inefficiently?

Tags: regex

I was given a link to the following article regarding the implementation of regular expressions in many modern languages.

http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

TL;DNR:  Certain regular expressions such as `(a?)^na^n` for fixed $n$ take exponential time matched against, say, `a^n` because its implemented via backtracking over the string when matching the `?` section.  Implementing these as an NFA by keeping state lists makes this much more efficient for obvious reasons

The details of how each language actually implements these isn't very detailed (and the article is old), but I'm curious: what, if any, are the drawbacks of using an NFA as opposed to other implementation techniques.  The only thing I can come up with is that with all the bells and whistles of most libraries either a) building a NFA for all those features is impractical or b) there is some conflicting performance issue between the expression above and some other, possibly more common, operation.

Comment: You're confusing DFAs and backtracing. While a DFA may be of exponential size (w.r.t. the equivalent NFA), once constructed it will run in linear time (w.r.t. the input string length). Backtracking is the approach that takes exponential time (w.r.t. the input string length), and it has very little to do with DFAs. But the question is still interesting after fixing that mistake.

Comment: @delnan - yep, you're correct. edited.  Backtracking is more like explicity enumerating all the paths in the NFA....

Comment: That article you link to has a troubling statement `"these fancy new regular expressions"`. He's haranging Perl & company for extended modern constructs. Sounds like he's got an axe to grind.

Comment: `(a?)^na^n` is not a regular expression the way the term is usually used (`grep`, `perl`, `awk`, `sed`, et al). For example, `^` generally matches the beginning of a string or line. I presume that's some syntax that I'm not immediately familiar with. Can you translate it into some more common regexp syntax, just for the sake of clarity?

Comment: @KeithThompson The notation is explained in the page linked to, and really not that obscure because analogous notation is used in formal language theory (in lieu of superscript/exponentiation, when constrained to ASCII). `p^n` is "`p` repeated n times".

Comment: There is a good discussion: http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=1195549

Comment: @KeithThompson Conventional modern syntax would be `p{n}` but the author is using more mathematical syntax (superscripts) and it is our questioner who is rendering them confusingly.

Comment: Here are some superscript n's for everyone: ⁿ ⁿ ⁿ ⁿ ⁿ ⁿ ⁿ ⁿ . Let me know if you require more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is possible to construct DFAs that handle these complex cases well (the [Tcl RE engine](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/artifact/0c529df480d9e435), which was written by Henry Spencer, is a proof by example; the article linked indicated this with its performance data) it's also exceptionally hard.

One key thing though is that if you can detect that you never need the matching group information, you can then (for many REs, especially those without internal backreferences) transform the RE into one that *only uses parentheses for grouping* allowing a more efficient RE to be generated (so `(a?){n}a{n}` — I'm using modern conventional syntax — becomes effectively equivalent to `a{n,2n}`). Backreferences break that major optimisation; it's not for nothing that in Henry's RE code (alluded to above) there is a code comment describing them as the “Feature from the Black Lagoon”. It is one of the best comments I've ever read in code (with the exception of references to academic papers that describe the algorithm encoded).

On the other hand, the Perl/PCRE style engines with their recursive-descent evaluation schemes, can ascribe a much saner set of semantics to mixed greediness REs, and many other things besides. (At the extreme end of this, recursive patterns — `(?R)` *et al* — are completely impossible with automata-theoretic approaches. They *require* a stack to match, making them formally not be regular expressions.)

On a practical level, the cost of building the NFA and the DFA you then compile that to can be quite high. You need clever caching to make it not too expensive. And also on a practical level, the PCRE and Perl implementations have had a lot more developer effort applied to them.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the main reason is we're not just interested in whether a string matches, but in *how* it matches, e.g. with capturing groups. For example, `(x*)x` needs to know how many xs were in the group so it can be returned as a capturing group. Similarly it "promises" to consume as many x characters as possible, which matters if we continue matching more things against the remaining string.

Some simpler types of expressions *could* be matched in the efficient way the article describes, and I have no special knowledge of why this isn't done. Presumably it's more effort to write two separate engines, and perhaps the extra time analyzing an expression to determine which engine to use on it is expensive enough that it's better to skip that step for the common case, and live with the very poor performance in the worst case.

Comment: Well, that page claims (in the section "Real world regular expressions") that it *is* possible to adopt Thompson's algorithm to extract groups, and refers to an existing implementation. However, this extension appears to be rather obscure/little known, so ignorance of it may be excused. It's also possible that the extension has other limitations which the author isn't aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

http://haifux.org/lectures/156/PCRE-Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expression_Library.pdf

They write that pcre uses NFA based implementation. But this link also not the youngest thing on the web...

Around the page 36 there is comparison between engines. It can also be relevant to the original question.